# Clip UIView using UIBezierPath in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, core-graphics, uibezierpath

As in image attached, can anyone guide me how I can clip the background view based on the bezierpath layer added on it.

Thanks in advance!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Need to clip the top portion or bottom portion?

Comment: @iDev need to clip top portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following class:

> UIBezierPathView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIBezierPathView : UIView

- (instancetype) initWithBezierPath:(UIBezierPath *)bezierPath;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *fillColor;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *strokeColor;

@end
```

> UIBezierPathView.m

```
#import "UIBezierPathView.h"



@interface UIBezierPathView()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *bezierPath;

@end

@implementation UIBezierPathView

- (id) initWithBezierPath:(UIBezierPath *)bezierPath
{
    self = [self initWithFrame:bezierPath.bounds];
    if(self)
    {
        self.bezierPath = bezierPath.copy;
        [self.bezierPath applyTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-CGRectGetMinX(self.frame), -CGRectGetMinY(self.frame))];
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.strokeColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.strokeColor setStroke];
    [self.fillColor setFill];
    [self.bezierPath fill];
    [self.bezierPath stroke];
}

@end
```

Comment: This will be difficult with the gradient fill that he wants.

Comment: I don't understand what will be difficult.

Comment: Actually, no. This will just recreate the image that he has in the question. He wants to use the path to mask the background image.

Comment: I though that it is another view.

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv I have used this class but bezierpath is not filling. Can you suggest me what can be the reason?

Comment: Could you please provide screenshot?

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv I have added new picture with blue line into the description.

Comment: You can use clear fillColor and create another background view with  gradient. Or add backgroundView property to UIBezierPathView.

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv Can you update it in your answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57872/discussion-between-hassan-ilyas-and-sviatoslav-yakymiv).

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv do you have any update for me?

Answer (score 2):

To clip the top part you may use belowLine

```
UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[aPath appendPath:pathExact];//Path exact is your original path drawn
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width, 0)];
[aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[aPath closePath];

CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.path = aPath.CGPath;
[self.layer setMask:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: There's a very good example of doing exactly this from WWDC 2013 (I think).